# Colored Circle background not showing behind number

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have a blue colored circle behind the number 1. The number is showing, but for some reason the background color isn't.

Here's my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/huskydawgs/8qzgf2uy/3/

Here's my code:

```
<div class="circle rtecenter"><span class="number">1</span></div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.circle-gray {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    width: 2em;
    text-align: center;
    background: #616161;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.circle-gray .number {
    margin-top: 0.10em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.4em;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.rtecenter {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You spelled the class-name wrong that's it:

`.circle` instead of `.circle-gray`

http://jsfiddle.net/8qzgf2uy/4/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a joke or a rel question.

Do you realize that in your div you are referencint to a class which do not exist?

You don't have in your CSS a class '.circle' that's why this do not work.

Comment: I was joking....and I always like to give explanation in my answers and not just post the solution. I am always glad to help. But anyway you up voted the other answer. Have a Merry Christmas